# While Loops Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I need to create an infinite loop based off a users response, however, I keep getting stuck after the while loop. To me it appears that I would need to just copy/paste my prior code since it would generate a new question for the user to respond to. Can someone give me some insight and or material to read over to get a better understanding?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create Scanner object for user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Declare variable for number of questions correct
    int correctQuestions = 0;

    // Declare variable for number of questions overall
    int overallQuestions = 0;

      // Generate two random single-digit integers for math equation
      int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
      int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

      // If number1 < number2, swap number 1 with number2
      if(number1 < number2){
          int temp = number1;
          number1 = number2;
          temp = number2;
    }
    // Ask the user to answer the mathematical questions 
    System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " x " + number2 + "?");
    int answer = input.nextInt();

    if(number1 * number2 == answer){
        System.out.print("Correct. You are a genius!");
        correctQuestions++;
        overallQuestions++;
    }
    else
        System.out.print("Sorry, looks like you'll have to try again");

    while(number1 * number2 == answer ^ number1 * number2 != answer)
        System.out.print("Would you like to try another question ? ");
    String response = input.nextLine();

    if(response == "y"){
            // Generate two random single-digit integers for math equation
          int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
          int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

          // If number1 < number2, swap number 1 with number2
          if(number1 < number2){
              int temp = number1;
              number1 = number2;
              temp = number2;
         }
    // Ask the user to answer the mathematical questions 
    System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " x " + number2 + "?");
    int answer = input.nextInt();

    if(number1 * number2 == answer){
        System.out.print("Correct. You are a genius!");
        correctQuestions++;
        overallQuestions++;
    }
    else
        System.out.print("Sorry, looks like you'll have to try again");
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nows a good time to learn a about the debugger in your IDE

Comment: I'm looking at the debugger but I'm confused as to why it's stating that the variables have already been declared. Would I have to create a new variable for each question being asked? Main.java:44: error: variable number1 is already defined in method main(String[])
      int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare `String`s!

Comment: You have two uses of `int answer =`... The second one only needs to be `answer =`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line: `number1 * number2 == answer ^ number1 * number2 != answer`?

Comment: Your swap is incorrect: `// If number1 < number2, swap number 1 with number2
      if(number1 < number2){
          int temp = number1;
          number1 = number2;
          temp = number2;
    }`

Comment: The omission of braces from your if's and while's makes the code harder to read

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question to say exactly what you're trying to achieve with the above code and what issues you're having. It will make it easier to get help.

Comment: I'm basically displaying a math questions to the user, if the answer is correct, then I need to use a while loop to ask them if they would like to continue with more questions or exit the application. However, my while loop will not continue on with a new question if they reply "yes," to the question asking if they would like to continue.

Answer (score 0):

completely renew your code like this

```
// Create Scanner object for user input
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Declare variable for number of questions correct
int correctQuestions = 0;

// Declare variable for number of questions overall
int overallQuestions = 0;

// Generate two random single-digit integers for math equation
int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

// If number1 < number2, swap number 1 with number2
if(number1<number2)
{
    int temp = number1;
    number1 = number2;
    number2=temp;
}//if 


while(true)
{
    System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " x " + number2 + "?");
    int answer = input.nextInt();
    overallQuestions++;
    if(number1*number2 == answer)
    {
        System.out.println("you are correct");
        correctQuestions++;

        break;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("sorry.. looks like you have to do whatever");
        System.out.println("would you like to do another crap put y for yep and n for nop");
        String response = input.next();

        if(response.equals("y"))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(response.equals("n"))
        {
            break;
        }

    }
}


System.out.println("overall questions:"+ overallQuestions + " correct ones:" + correctQuestions);
```

Comment: what is the difference between using == "y" and response.equals("y")?

Comment: there is no =="y". string is an object and not a value so it has its own methods one of them being .equals() so you souldn't use =="y" for string objects

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer ill be so glad if you check my post as the answer and rate it up. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Start by determining if you have implemented all aspects of the project that you need. Generally speaking, once this is done, you'll have several options to build on the project. In this case, you want the program to continue until the user quits. So check to see if you have any variables that indicate their decision. If so, a loop with a conditional checking that variable for a specific value will work well.

**Several things to mention**

Several variables are declared twice. If they need to be separate variables then new variable names will need to be assigned. Otherwise, they don't need to be declared twice just remember to set the value to the initial starting point before using them again.

Also, I would highly recommend using brackets after conditional statements. It is personal preference but it's easier to tell which conditionals apply to which pieces of code.